# How do I get the name of the variable with the highest value in an iterable?

Tags: python, list

I need Python to analyze a long list of numbers stored in variables and pick the highest one. I need it to tell me which variable is the highest.

This is what I think I need (it's not actual code):

```
variable1 = 1000
variable2 = 242
variable3 = 87509
highest_number = pick_highest(variable1, variable2 ,variable3 )
print(highest_number)
```

Output:

```
"variable3"
```

Comment: I found [about 160,000,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+max+of+list). Are you _sure_ you found none?

Comment: Sort them, grab the last one, done. Don't try to overcomplicate extremely straightforward tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the max() Function to Find Max Value in a List in Python.

Python has a pre-defined function called max() that returns the maximum value in a list.

Finding the maximum value using max() will only need a single line.

`numbers = [55, 4, 92, 1, 104, 64, 73, 99, 20] max_value = max(numbers)`
`print('Maximum value:', max_value) Output: Maximum value: 104`

Comment: If the list is a set of variables (containing numbers) will it tell me which variable had the highest number?

Comment: 1. Google the Pearson correlation coefficient. (a measure of the linear association between two variables) 

2. Use Numpy's corrcoef() function:

`np.corrcoef(var1, var 2)`